# How do I setup DNS for a local email server with a SMTP relay

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, smtp, relay

I'm trying to move my mail server (multi domain) to my home to increase security/privacy.

Therefore I set up a local server and a SMTP relay (postfix) on a hosted VPS (because of static IP, etc.).
Sending the email works but the email gets rejected due to wrong settings (MX_INVALID, MID_RHS_NOT_FQDN, R_PARTS_DIFFER, RCVD_NO_TLS_LAST, etc.).

Preq:

- main.Domain1.de -> Used as the hostname for the email server
- Domain2.de -> Used for sending emails
- Domain3.de -> Used for sending emails

The following questions for this topic:

- DKIM / DMARC needs to be done on the local server or the relay?
- What about the DNS settings? (Currently main.Domain1.de + MX is targeted to the IP of the VPS, Domain2.de MX is set to 'main.Domain1.de', Domain2.de * and A is targeted to my private IP)

As a general question:

- Is all done trough the relay (Incoming emails as well) or do I need to expose my local mail server with port 25 to receive emails?